Intel Corporation 7 Series/C216 ChipsetController not working in ubuntu
I am fairly new to Ubuntu and Linux
I am having problems getting my sound to work, when I play a YouTube video, I don't get any audio from the rear ports either from my speakers or headphones, however I can hear it through my headphones when plugged into the front audio socket
Can someone please help me, so I can completely ditch Windows
Thanks
Ian

Check your wiring, to make sure everything is in order.

Work with alsmixer https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Audio/Alsamixer, if the sound is muted on alsamixer press f6 choose the sound card press f5 and go to the channel you want press m to add or remove the muting.
there are 2 gui apps that are available:
pavucontrol which is a simpler app
https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/focal/man1/pavucontrol.1.html
install: sudo apt install pavucontrol
If you are on Ubuntu 24.04 easyeffects.
Install: sudo apt install easyeffects
They are both good but usually you have to first use alsamixer first to get everything in order.
There is a lot of pages on internet which describes how to install
I have not used any flatpak packages and so far did not have any need to.


@Ian Bardell also follow link that moo sent.

I found the cause of the problem, I had a USB device, that had an onboard sound card plugged it and it was picking up that instead of the rear ports
